# VS 2005 professional edition x86

Tags: visual-studio-2005, installation

I am trying to install vs 2005 professional editon x86 on vista.
My machine and operating system both are 64 bit. When I start setup it shows .net framework for 64 bit. I exit from the installation. can anybody help me out?
Is it normal that 32 bit application become 64 bit on 64 bit vista and machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whats happening is that the .NET framework prerequisite is detecting that you are on a x64 machine. Its going to install both the x86 and x64 versions of the .NET framework. You can still develop x86 applications without any issues on a x64 machine. You can also run x86 applications on a x64 machine without any issues.

And, there is no x64 version of Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, VSStudio 05 x86 will show that it will install x86 & x64 version of .NET even on 32 bit machine. But I think it does not install x64 .NET on a 32 bit machine.
What I would suggest is you go ahead & let the install run & if there are any errors(google it else) post it here at SO.